# How does "Show only visible features" work in Map Composer?

Tags: qgis, printing

If I tick show only visible, I get no features.

I have created an attribute table in the Map Composer in QGIS trunk 
QGIS version 1.9.90-Alpha QGIS code revision 4d6cc6d
I note recent feature update http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4496
but this doesn't explain my experience. I suspect it is misuse on my part.

**I would like to select a feature in the main attribute table in QGIS, then have it show only the label for that feature and show only that row in the attribute table in Print Composer.**

I explored the options considerably I think, when I uncheck the box I get as many rows as the setting will allow, no relationship to visible. I have checked the Map 1 in the dropdown.

---

I have written this much, maybe it will help someone else...
I am going to explore reloading the layer, it is in fact a delimited text layer since I am using the read only status of that layer to provide some versioning control. Will see what happens when I reload it as a shapefile.

This is cutting edge cartography as far as my skillset is concerned....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **"Show only visible features"** option of an attribute table in Print Composer makes sure that only the attributes of currently visible features are listed. "Visible" means that the feature is within the current extent of the map as it is set up in Print Composer (and NOT in the main window).

This can easily be tested, e.g. by loading a point layer, then changing to Print Compser, adding map & attribute table and then zooming in. You will notice that the attribute table starts getting shorter if fewer features are within the map extents.

Comment: Ok, that is very much the case for QGIS 1.7.4 and a brand new map/composer in Trunk- many thanks AG.

Comment: Now I have to find what is the bug/glitch in my project that stops it working.

Comment: The project crs has to be the same as the layer crs for the system to work (which is a reasonable limitation).  I am using openlayers as an underlay in the composer so it likes to reset the projection to google mercator.

Comment: So once the openlayers plugin is enabled, the crs can be set back to a UTM which is the same as the layer and the map composer in QGIS is able to work magic on a number of levels !! The "Show only visible features" option on the attribute table works a treat and all layers of the map appear to be properly projected ready for printing. Brilliant!